# R Delete rows in data frame at a particular value

Tags: r

Considering a generic data frame with these parameters:

```
up <- seq(10,60,2)
down <- seq(50,0,-2)
df <- data.frame(time = seq(1,104,2), b = c(up, down), c = rnorm(52, 6, 3))
```

in which the parameter b increases and then decreases;

How can I delete the rows that are after the max(b) considering the sequence of "time"?

In other words, I want to obtain the data frame above max(b).

I was thinking to determine the row number at max(b)

```
which(df$b == max(df$b))
```

then, to use data.frame to remove the rows < of that row value

Comment: `df[1:which.max(df$b),]`

Comment: `df[1:which(df[,'b'] == max(df[,'b'])),]` - cpak got there as I was typing this out :)

Comment: Use the `dplyr` package to avoid having to sort the dataframe first. This will return all rows after max(b) regardless of how the dataframe is ordered:  `dplyr::filter(df,time < df[which(df[,'b'] == max(df[,'b'])),]$time)`